# Cross-Region AWS Glue Data Catalog access with Glue ETL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I have a Glue ETL job in a region us-west-2 that reads from database from AWS Glue Data Catalog from that region. Example

```py
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='my-database',
                                                            table_name='my-table');
```

I want to access AWS Glue Catalog cross region using glue job. So how can glue job in us-west-2 read AWS Glue database from us-east-1 belonging to the same account number?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for that?